# Force lambda to re-evaluate as part of Rx sequence

Tags: c#, lambda, system.reactive

I am trying to generate progress messages and publish them via an `IObservable`.

```
Func<JobProgressMessage> nextMsg = () => ProgressManager.InProgressMessage("progressing");

var o = Observable
    .Return(nextMsg())
    .Repeat()
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .Retry(100)
    .Finally(() =>
        job.AddMessage<ProgressCompleted>(ProgressManager.CompletedMessage("Completed")));
```

I am finding that the `nextMsg()` gets evaluated just the once and the same message gets published. I was hoping that the `Repeat` would cause the lambda to re-evaluate each time.

Comment: `map`/`select` using a function/lambda to create new messages

Comment: one solution, you can return nextMsg function (not nextMsg()), at subscriber, you will call that function `o.Subscribe(k =>
            {
                  var msg = k();
            });`

Comment: Thx to both. Easiest fix seemed to be adding message as part of subscribing.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do here? Even with Daniel's answer this observable just continues producing values indefinitely without end.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I was simply trying to generate progress messages which were staggered over time so that I could test a progress bar component across the web ... I ended up using .Delay(..).Repeat(100) .. instead of the Timeout(..).Retry() stuff. I'll update my answer. thx

Comment: @SimonWoods - You should probably use `Observable.Generate(...)` for this. It's very powerful.

Comment: @Enigmativity - thx for the heads up ... I'll have a look at that operator. (Although perhaps the name should have given me a clue!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to re-evaluate something each time your observable is subscribed to (that includes repeated subscriptions by `Repeat`), `Defer` is what you want:

```
Func<JobProgressMessage> nextMsg = () => ProgressManager.InProgressMessage("progressing");

var o = Observable
    .Defer(() => Observable
        .Return(nextMsg()))
    .Repeat()
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .Retry(100)
    .Finally(() => job.AddMessage<ProgressCompleted>ProgressManager.CompletedMessage("Completed")));
```

Basically, on subscription, `Defer` evaluates the passed in function to get a fresh observable on each subscription. Then, of course `nextMsg` will be re-evaluated too.

Answer (score 0):

Following nhabuiduc's suggestion, the easiest way was

```
var o = Observable.Return(ProgressManager.InProgressMessage("progressing"))
                          .Repeat()
                          .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                          .Retry(100)
                          .Finally(() => job.AddMessage<ProgressCompleted>(ProgressManager.CompletedMessage("Completed")));

var s = o.Subscribe(m => job.AddMessage(ProgressManager.InProgressMessage("progressing")));
```

but in the end, cos I wanted to play with Observables, I ended up with

```
var s = Observable.Defer(()=>Observable.Return(nextMsg()))
                  .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                  .Repeat(100)
                  .Finally(() => job.AddMessage<ProgressCompleted>(ProgressManager.CompletedMessage("Completed")))
                  .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
                  .Subscribe(m => job.AddMessage(m));
```